# Create submodules from a already created bitbucket repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-submodules, git-clone, bitbucket-server

Hello I am using `git` and the web interface `bitbucket`
I have the following structure in bitbucket

```
a
|-b
|-c
```

Thing is I want to be able to `clone` only `c`. I have red that `submodules` are the way to go.

How can I make `c` a submodule and clone it somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

To achive the shown structure, you have to split your repository `a` in three different repositories `a`, `b` and `c`, and add repository `b` and `c` as submodules to your parent repository `a`.

[This](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) describes how to create a new repository from a subfolder of an existing one. Steps later than step 5 have to be adapted to bitbucket instead of GitHub, of course, but the process will be quite similar. If you do that for `b` and `c` (and for `a` if it contains any other files or folders than `b` and `c`, else you can just initialize a new empty repository) and add the submodules, you achieved your goal.

You should, however, defnitielty read about submodules before you use them (e.g. [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Starting-with-Submodules) or [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407)), especially before you undertake such a serious reconstruction of your repository. Remember you will break the workflow for everyone who might still be working on your code.